# Json property coming back null despite having value

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am making a call to a mongodb to get a list of values but one of the properties is coming back null, even though it has a value. I will try to give as much info as possible.

**call to to get shipment info**

```
var mobs = new List<ShipmentInformation>();
mobs = await GetAll();
```

**Definition of GetAll() method:**

```
 public abstract class GenericDocumentRepository<TEntity> : IGenericDocumentRepository<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IQueryable where TEntity : IEntity
    {
          public virtual Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll();
}
```

**Shipmentinformation class:**

```
 public class ShipmentInformation : ResourceObject<string, ShipmentInformationAttributes, ShipmentInformationRelationships>
    {
        public override string type { get; set; }
       public override ShipmentInformationAttributes attributes { get; set; 
      }    

        public override ShipmentInformationRelationships 
        relationships { get; set; }
      }


  public class ShipmentInformationRelationships : RelationshipsObject
    {
 public JobInfo Job { get; set; }
    }

  public class JobInfo
        {
            public List<JobData> data { get; set; }            
}
```

**Result:**

[image] }

**here is image of data from mongo**

[image]

As you can see job in mongo is not null but result says its null.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JobInfo
{
        public List<JobData> Data { get; set; }            
}
```

Should be named **D**ata, so that the casing matches that of your Mongo Object.

However it would also be possible to add a BsonElement Attribute like this

```
public class JobInfo
{
        [BsonElement("Data")]
        public List<JobData> data { get; set; }            
}
```